# How do you run your own Docker continuous build?

Tags: docker

I'm fairly new to Docker but I've built a few images for my various projects now and getting the hang of doing things "manually". Docker Hub's got great automated build functionality but its pricey. How can one replicate that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have enough reputations to comment on your question as this is more of a comment.

If your repository (private/public) is on bitbucket or github, then the automated build functionality comes out of box. More [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/)

```
Use of automated builds requires that you have an account on Docker Hub and 
on the hosted repository provider (GitHub or Bitbucket). 
If you have previously linked your Github or Bitbucket account, 
you must have chosen the Public and Private connection type. 
To view your current connection settings, 
from your Docker Hub account choose Profile > Settings > Linked Accounts & Services.
```

If you do not want to go in that direction, and have it in house, as of today, there are couple of options, one of them would be to use in-house docker registry with some CI engine of your choice.

e.g. Jenkins to do the autobuilding (polling for changes and building) and docker registry to do the holding. We have been doing this, not bad.

However, you will have the couple of drawbacks such as, lacking a UI, search functionality etc.

Comment: RE "out of the box" from Docker Hub. Yes, I have used that and it's very cool but multiple private builds gets expensive.

Apparently the answer is Jenkins. Not sure how, but Jenkins.